# What are the meanings of the values in the Android "content//sms/" content provider?

Tags: android, sms, android-contentprovider

I queried "content//sms/" and I don't know what some fields mean. They are -

1. Thread ID
2. Protocol
3. Status
4. Reply_Path_Present
5. Service_Center

I checked them in LogCat and found the values to be these:

- Thread ID : 1 to 6 etc..
- Protocol : null / 0
- Status : -1
- Reply_Path_Present : null / 0
- Service_Center : null

Please tell me what the meanings of those values are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Cursor.getColumnNames()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getColumnNames()) to retrieve the column names of any content provider, e.g.

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(
    Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);

String[] columnNames = cursor.getColumnNames();
```

For `content://sms/inbox` this yields _id, thread_id, address, person, date, protocol, read, status, type, reply_path_present, subject, body, service_center, locked on my phone.

You can also have a look at the [`SmsProvider`](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/providers/TelephonyProvider.git;a=blob_plain;f=src/com/android/providers/telephony/SmsProvider.java;hb=HEAD) but it is not part of the public API.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Josef. sorry for my weakness in English. I mean as an example, what it means in value of status '-1'. Are there just 15 fields of content//sms? Does it depend on Android version? Where and how could I learn the open source code like ur shared link, SmsProvider? Actually, I've worked in Android for 2 months. So let me know more.

Comment: The SMS content provider itself is "not part of the public API". If it were, you would see classes for it in the `android.provider` package. See http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/be-careful-with-content-providers.html

Comment: Thank you. let me know that the above 5 fields are used for what.

Comment: This is a correct answer but for a different question i suppose !

Answer (score 1):

The folling is  the way to determine all the columns that a particular Cursor has .

```
StringBuffer info = new StringBuffer();
for( int i = 0; i < Cursor.getColumnCount(); i++) {
    info.append("Column: " + Cursor.getColumnName(i) + "\n");
}
```

Print this out to know what are all  the columns in the table .